# Excel 2013: Automatic data update from external URL

Tags: excel, csv, url

I have a webservice which continuously generate/update a csv file which can be downloaded externally. I would like to use an Excel file to continuously get the content of the csv file, and do calculation and visualization accordingly.

e.g.
my csv file contains 4 rows, 3 columns.
In an Excel sheet, A1:C4 are used to store the contents of the csv file. A5:C5 are the average of each column. And a bar chart of the contents in each column is displayed in A5.

How can I ask the Excel to download the csv file by specifying its URL, and store in A1:C4? And how to make it automatically update its contents when the csv file is updated?

Comment: You might want to install Power Query in Excel and then look at linking an external data source.

Comment: I have tried power query, but it seems that after loading, the excel entries cannot get updated automatically when the source csv is updated. How could I get automatic update in excel?

Comment: Power Query will update every time you open the workbook.  You can also update it with VBA so if you need it to auto refresh while the workbook is open, you could write a routing the refreshes every xx minutes.